# Battery drain - 2001 Chevy Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, power, battery-drain, malibu, electronic-control-module

I'm trying to troubleshoot a parasitic battery drain and need help. With all courtesy lights off, key out, doors shut, I show 1.5A of draw. The battery is dead within 24 hrs.

I have pulled all fuses by the doors with very little difference.

Inside the fuse box under the hood, if I pull PCM ACC fuse, the draw goes from 1.5A to 0.6A. When I disconnect the IAC, the draw goes from 1.5A to 1.0A.

Not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: "if I pull PCM ACC fuse, the draw goes from 1.5A to 0.6A" there is your problem, it will need professional diagnosis, either a bad PCM or other device keeping the PCM in an active state.

Comment: Any way to diagnose it myself? Is there a way to determine why the PCM is still active with a diag tool?

Comment: Too expensive for the DIY.

Comment: Decided to purchase a PriorityStart to automatically disconnect the battery. Rather than spending lots of money on a school car, decided to take the band aid approach. After a few days, seems to have resolved the issue..